# Who creates the viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I work on a big webapp developed in .NET 4.0.30319. We switched `ViewState` off setting the property of the page `EnableViewState` to false; a security vulnerability was raised since I don't encrypt the `ViewState`.

I realized that some data is stored in the `ViewState` and is just base64 encoded. It was just 50 bytes containing a number (looks like an Id) and a string containing the word control.

Who stores this data, is the `ViewState` created by default by ASP .NET although is turned off? Since `EnableViewState` is set to false, no application relevant data should be stored in the `ViewState`, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewState is a ASP.net or Server Side Object (Entity) and as such it follows that it exists (SAVED) on the Server but is sent back and forth (on post-Backs).

Your question does not make it clear what is the goal you are trying to achieve by disabling the ViewState, but generally speaking you would do this primarily to address performance issues. If that is not you objective, I would reconsider enabling it. As you probably have gathered the ViewState is enabled by default at the page and control level.

here are some helpful MSDN links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx